# Looking for a YA horror anthology (90s?), all took place at The Something Academy

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, horror

As a kid, I remember reading a series of Goosebumps-like books.  They were all written by the same author, I think, and there were a half-dozen or so that I (vaguely) remember.  The stories all centered around kids attending the...something Academy (my memory wants to say that it sounded something like 'Chaleen,' but that could be way off).

I recall one book about a mummy on the grounds.  I think there was a vampire installment as well.

It's not much to go on, but if it rings a bell in your head, please let me know!  Thanks!

Comment: It couldn't possibly be the 'Bailey School Kids' series, could it? I realize this doesn't feature an 'Academy', but it is a goosebumps-like series with over 80 books (first book released in 1991), all based around the Bailey school, and the series included a possible mummy as a softball coach and at least twice featured a vampire as the monster of the week.

Comment: Definitely not, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you be thinking of the "*Nightmare Hall*" series, by Diane Hoh? It focuses on a number of students attending Salem University. These were published in the early to mid-1990s.

Here is a link to all of the books, with cover images and plot summaries: http://www.goodreads.com/series/49955-nightmare-hall

This was a spin-off of the *Point Horror* series, started by R. L. Stine.

If this is the series you are thinking of, the "mummy on the loose" book is, I believe, Student Body.
[image]

Comment: Nope.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose it could be this?

[image: Dragon Slayer's Academy: The New Kid At School]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Terror Academy books by Nicolas Pine. There were 15 of them, each featuring a different teenager. You can read the synopsis for all 15 here:
http://www.scaryforkids.com/terror-academy/

Answer (score 0):

Phantom Valley books take place at Chilleen Academy.

Comment: Can you expand on this at all? Any details *about* the books you can add in?